# Unused private methods, private fields and local variables

Tags: java, sonarqube

We are using Sonar to review our codebase. There are few violations for Unused private method, Unused private field and Unused local variable.

As per my understanding private methods and private fields can be accessed outside of the class only through reflection and Java Native Interface. We are not using JNI in our code base, but using reflection in some places.

So what we are planning is to do a complete `workspace` search for these methods and fields and if these are not used anywhere even through reflection, then these will be commented out. Again chances for accessing private methods and fields through reflection are very less. This is for safer side.

Unused local variables can’t be accessed outside of the method. So we can comment out these.

Do you have any other suggestions about this?

Comment: Don't comment out the code, remove it. If you have to put it back for some reason later, that is what version control is for.

Comment: So there is no other risks to remove this right.

Comment: There are risks as long as there is reflection. The use of fields/methods through reflection can only be determined at runtime. For that reason, double check your reflection code and only then remove the fields. Always keep your reflection code to a minimium and at very localized/defined places and uses.

Comment: I am not sure whether the unused methods or fields indicated by Sonar are used through reflection or not. For checking this only I am doing a codebase search. I think if a field or method need to be used through reflection, then that method or field name should be used. So my understanding is it can be identified through a code search.

Comment: Don't worry if they are used reflectively... that's why God invented testing. If they're used, your integration/system tests will explode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I love reflection myself, but to put it in a few words: it can be a nightmare. Keep java reflection to a very controlable (that is, stateless, no global/external variable usage) and minimal scope.

### What to look for?

To find private fields and methods turned public, look for [`Field#setAccessible()` and `Method#setAccessible()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29), such as the examples below:

```
Field privateNameField = Person.class.getDeclaredField("name");
privateNameField.setAccessible(true);

Method privatePersonMethod = Person.class.getDeclaredMethod("personMeth", null);
privatePersonMethod.setAccessible(true);
```

So, `setAccessible()` will get you some smoke, but `getDeclaredField()` and `getDeclaredMethod()` are really where the fields are accessed (what really makes the fire).

Pay special attention to the values used in them, specially if they are variables (they probably will be), as they are what determine the field accessed.

### Do a plain text search

Also, doing a **plain text search** for the field/method name on the whole project folder is very useful. I'd say, if you are not sure, **don't delete before doing a full text search**.

If you have many other projects that depend on this one you are trying to change; and if you weren't (or didn't know) the guy who planted those (bombs), I'd let it go. Only would change if really really needed to. The best action would be to get them one by one when you need to make a change to a code around it.

Ah, and, if you have them, running tests with **code coverage** can also help you big time in spotting unused code.

Answer (score 0):

Calling an unused method via reflection is just weird. And unused fields are could only be used as a deposit via reflection, and used via reflection. Weird too.

Reflection is more in use as a generic bean copying tool.

So a radical clean-up should be absolutely unproblematic. It would be time better spent to look into the usages of java.reflect; whether the reflection code is legitimate. That is more intelligent work than looking for usage of private fields in strings.

And yes, remove it from the source code, which speeds up reading by seconds.

*(Of course I understood that this a question of the type: did I oversee something.)*

Comment: I am not sure whether the unused methods or fields indicated by Sonar are used through reflection or not. But chances are very very less. But again doing a search to make sure this.