# How to determine whether "unused" private fields in Java are actually being used by Spring?

Tags: java, spring, sonarqube, pmd

We use Sonar/pmd to report when a private field is declared and/or assigned a value, but not used.  These can be erroneous reports in certain circumstances, [for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513857/unused-private-methods-private-fields-and-local-variables), when reflection is used.

The Spring framework does various things using reflection.  How can I determine whether a supposedly unused Java field is actually being used by Spring?

Answer (score 1):

If a private field is going to be used from outside the class, this can only be done through reflection. Besides the framework you mention, you could have false positives with Struts 2 (and any other framework that uses reflection)

Answer (score 0):

The main cause of false positives is indeed the usage of Reflection. Reflection occurs at runtime, therefore static code analysis has a hard time taking it into account.
Almost all of the popular frameworks (Spring, Hibernate, even Java EE) heavily use reflection (often in conjunction with annotations) to simplify their use.
So if you use any of those frameworks, there is a high chance PMD, Checkstyle and al. will trigger false positives.

On the other hand, if I may suggest, it is usually a bad idea to use static analysis tools with their default settings, as they may apply certain rules that may not be adequate to your architecture.
The "unused field" one is among the rules I usually disable (along with line length, etc.), so that I can concentrate on the really important ones (empty catch block, bad use of threads, etc.)